# Uploading code from C# application to Arduino UNO

Tags: c#, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

A Windows form C# application, it uploads the attendance using Arduino UNO and a finger print sensor attached with it. I am using a library 
["ArduinoSketchUploader"](https://github.com/christophediericx/ArduinoSketchUploader).

Now the problem is when I try to upload the sketch to enroll finger prints while a sketch to match finger prints is already uploaded it gives me an exception.

> System.IO.IO.Exception: Unable to establish sync after 20  retires.

But it works fine when I upload a sketch to delete finger prints while a sketch to enroll finger prints is already uploaded and vice versa.

Here is the code:

```
var uploader = new ArduinoSketchUploader(
    new ArduinoSketchUploaderOptions()
    {
        FileName = "C:\Users\Rizwan\Desktop\delete.ino.hex",
        PortName = sp.PortName,
        ArduinoModel = ArduinoModel.UnoR3
    }
);
uploader.UploadSketch();
```

Comment: Why do you assume there is a problem with the code instead of a bad connection? Have you used the correct connection settings?

Comment: Also PLEASE check the Markdown help. It's very easy to write code snippets - just indent your code by 4 spaces.

Comment: Can you use the Arduino IDE? Have you specified the same port?

Comment: I can use Arduino IDE to upload the code but I don't to use Arduino IDE.

Comment: Can you **connect** using the Arduino IDE? What connection settings did you use there? Are you using the same settings in your code? If you can't connect with the IDE either, there's something wrong with your cable or settings.

Comment: Port : "COM5" in Arduino IDE and same Port in the application.